# Unable to find users to notify with test with Azure Notification Hub version Google (FCM v1)

Tags: azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have been reading about Fcm V1 due the migration of FCM by Google.
My application already has several numbers of users in Android and Apple platform.
I use Azure to centralize the administration so, Azure "talks" with FCM and APNS.

After the configuration in Google (FCM v1) in Azure (Private Key, Client Email and Project Id),
I have tried to make a "Test Send" BUT the message from Azure is unable to find any subscriber.

By the contrary, when I send a message using Android (Legacy) option it works fine.

**What expected to happen:**
When I sent a test message from azure notifications using Android (FCM v1), azure would be able to send a message and find an find users, in the same way when I send message with Android (Legacy)

What really happen:
When I send test message with Android (FCM v1), Azure was unable to find and notify any user.

My application already have several users with functional notifications in Android FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) and APNS
(Apple Notification Service), I do not want to think I have to migrate that users or something like that.

**What should I do to effectively my users receive notifications when I send a test using Google (FCM v1)?**

[image: Notification message not arrives]

[image: Unable to find subscribers]

[image: Unable to find users even when they exists]

[image: Summary]

Answer (score 0):

Your users needs to be registered through FCM V1 in order to receive notifications through FCM V1.

Somewhere in your code, there should be a functionality where the unique device token obtained from the mobile device is registered in respective notification services. This could be through Azure most of the time.

If you have all the active unique device tokens, you can run some kind of a bulk operation to register all of them through FCM V1. Then you will start receiving notification sent through FCM V1.

Read more here https://medium.com/@pramodyahk/migrating-to-fcm-v1-in-azure-notification-hubs-android-push-notifications-c342d76adfb2