FCMv1 Is Not Working In Azure Notification Hub
I Configured Correctly Provided In The Documentation(For FCMv1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/firebase-migration-rest.I am Trying Send Notification(Test Send) Directly From Azure Portal.I Am Not Getting Notification.
Anyone Getting Notifications Directly From Azure Portal.Please Help To Sort Out The Issue.
When I Send Request From Code The Graph Is Recording.Please Click Below Link To View Image.
enter image description here

The document you have provided is not accessible. Can you check and elaborate more on the issue. @ARUN PRASAD S

As I Aware FCM Legacy Is Going To Retire From June 20 Onwards. So I Trying To Migrate My Application To FCMv1.I Configured Everything In Firebase As Provided In Documentation. Through Sample Code And Directly From Portal I Give Notification. Through Code I Am Getting Tracking ID And Correlation ID But Notification Is Not Received In Mobile.T hrough Portal I Am Getting Below Response.  To Sort Out This Issue.

Same Question I Asked In Microsoft QA Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1667585/push-notification%28fcmv1%29-is-not-coming-from-azure?comment=question#newest-question-comment

Can you provide any reference MSDoc. @ARUN PRASAD S

This Document I Refered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/firebase-migration-rest

Issues Discussed:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1621493/azure-push-notification-hub-is-not-sending-notific
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1622469/test-notifications-with-fcmv1-sent-from-azure-hub
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183302/unable-to-find-users-to-notify-with-test-with-azure-notification-hub-version-goo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421477/migrating-azure-notification-hub-from-using-gcm-to-fcm-using-rest-api-call
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1658068/pushnotifications-upgrade-to-fcmv1-is-not-deliveri

In FCMv1 Before Sending Notification For Particular Device Using Tags,Register The Tags(DeviceId) Along With FCM Token.After That Send Notification Through Azure Portal It Will Work.

